# Difference between order isomorphism and order homomorphism

Tags: lattice-orders, morphism

I read on **Applied Abstract Algebra** by **Rudolf Lidl and Gunter Pilz** that if $L$ and $M$ be two lattices and $f:L\to M$ be a mapping, then $f$ is order homomorphism if $x\le y\implies f(x)\le f(y)$.

On the other hand, in **Introduction to Lattices and Order** by **B.A.Davey and H.A.Priestley**, it is said that $f$ is order isomomorphism if $x\le y\iff f(x)\le f(y)$.

Now these two are confusing me whether they are same or if there is any difference, is it just only 'if' and 'iff'?

Also if I am asked to show that $f$ is a bijective homomorphism (**is it equal to isomorphism?**), how do I show that? Because my knowledge says that to show bijection , I need to show both injection and surjection. And for homomorphism, I need to show join and meet-homomorphism. Here my **second question** arises how to show injective and surjective in this case? Is it same as injective and surjective mapping?

Answer (score 3):

Note that if $f$ is an order isomorphism, then $f$ must be one-to-one.

Indeed, if $f(x)=f(y)$ then $f(x) \leq f(y)$ implies $x \leq y$, while $f(y) \leq f(x)$ implies $y \leq x$. Therefore $x=y$.

The same is not true for order homomorphism, since any constant function satisfies the relation.

Now, with this observation, you can show the following, which makes the definition more clear:

**Lemma** Let $f:L\to M$ be any function. Then  $f$ is order isomomorphism if and only if
$f : L \to Im(f)$ is an order homomorphism and its inverse $f^{-1}:  Im(f) \to L$ is an order homomorphism.

*Note:* In general in mathematics, the difference between 'if' and 'iff' is often huge, so I would not say that the difference is **just** "if" and "iff".

Comment: how do I show a lattice function is injective? is it same as general function?

Comment: @ManjoyDas being one to one or onto is property of the function and its domain/codomain. The order structure of the lattices is not relevant here.

Comment: you said that $f $ is an order isomorphism, then $f$ must be one-to-one. Then what about onto?

Comment: @ManjoyDas This is why I put $Im(f)$ in the Lemma. Consider the case $L$ is a sublattice of $M$ and $f$ is the inclusion mapping.

Comment: so a monomorphism $f:L\to Im(f)$ is iso but a monomorphism $f:L\to M$ is not where $Im(f)\subset M$

Comment: can I say that if $f$ is join and meet homomorphism along with a bijection, then $f$ is  an isomorphism? i.e., join-homomorphism$+$ meet-homomorphism$+$bijection=isomorphism?